# SonarQube: How many hours in a day of technical debt?

Tags: sonarqube

If SonarQube says I have 1 day of technical debt in a project, does that translate to 24 hours of technical debt or 8 hours of technical debt?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The translation from hours into days is customisable. By default it's 8 hours, but you can find out your setting by going to Administration > Configuration > Technical Debt.

Screenshot of an example, from my project, below:

[image: tech debt configuration]

Comment: I'm working in a big company and I will not be able to contact the person who set up SonarQube, is there a way to check this if you are not an admin? Can I fetch that value with the API maybe?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found an obvious way of doing this. :( It might be possible to use the key 'sonar.technicalDebt.hoursInDay', but I haven't seen an API that allows it.