# SonarQube web API for Code smells - Technical Debt Count

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube6.3

SonarQube Version: 6.7

Is there any REST API for getting Code smells (Technical Debt) from SonarQube, I have searched many forums but I couldn't able to find.

I need rest API where we can pass the project key to get the days count of code smells.

Comment: What is "the days count of code smells"?

Comment: Edited - I mean Technical Debt Count

Answer (score 6):

Finally, I got the specific API for Technical Debt count for Code Smells type.

Use the below API which gives debtTotal count, take this figure and divide with mins configured in sonar [Number of working hours in a day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41652842/sonarqube-how-many-hours-in-a-day-of-technical-debt)

Rest API: http://sonarinstance/api/issues/search?componentKeys=sample-project:sample-projec-key&facetMode=effort&facets=types&types=CODE_SMELL

Sample Response:

[image]

For Example, if 8 Hrs configured divide with 480 Mins

Answer (score 3):

There is web api for measures:  https://sonar.instance/api/measures/component

Metric for Technical debt is "sqale_index" https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.4/user-guide/metric-definitions/

Query to search technical debt is:

https://**sonar.instance**/api/measures/component?component=**project_key**&metricKeys=sqale_index

Answer (score 1):

If I am not missing something, the following Web API should be the one you are looking for:
https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/issues?query=issues%2Fsearch

Look for `effort` in the Response Example tab and you will find the estimated time to fix each issue. The format is a bit unusual, but still it should not be difficult to parse.

Comment: @ [Valeri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7156760/valeri-sonarsource)  your answer helped me to find the exact rest API